# Creating multithread server in python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, http

I am newbie for implementing multithread web server in python. I searched the internet and found some resources to make it.After that I tested in apachebench via this command :

ab -n 1000 -c 5 localhost:8888/

Results for this command :

```
Concurrency Level:      5
Time taken for tests:   1.692 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Requests per second:    591.16 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       8.458 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.692 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
```

ab -n 1000 -c 100 localhost:8888/

Results :

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   1.699 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      12078000 bytes
HTML transferred:       12000000 bytes
Requests per second:    588.50 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       169.923 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.699 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          6941.33 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Now , My question is that Why these values(time taken for tests and request per second ..) is not change noticeable ? Can anyone interpret this test results ?

Code:

```
import thread
import socket
import sys

def threadFunction(client_connection,client_address):
    print 'Client thread created..'
    request = client_connection.recv(1024)
    print request
    if request=="":
    sys.exit()
    client_connection.send("HTTP/1.1 400 bad request\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\nContent-Lenght: "+b)
    client_connection.close()

HOST, PORT = '', 8888

listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
listen_socket.listen(100)


while True:
    print 'Serving HTTP on port %s ...' % PORT
    client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
    print 'client_connection: %s , client_address : %s' % (client_connection,client_address)
    try:
                thread.start_new_thread( threadFunction, (client_connection,client_address) ) 
    except IOError:
        print "Failed in initialize thread.."
listen_socket.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Threading in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190206/threading-in-python)

Comment: Why do you want to write a multi threaded server? I guess reusing is better than reinventing. Multiple **threads** and not processes?

Answer (score 1):

Actually  Apache is a single threaded benchmark tool  and Time taken for tests: is the time taken by the 'ab' to start test ..

**Concurrency versus Threads**

Note that ApacheBench will only use one operating system thread regardless of the concurrency level (specified by the -c parameter). In some cases, especially when benchmarking high-capacity servers, a single instance of ApacheBench can itself be a bottleneck. When using ApacheBench on hardware with multiple processor cores, additional instances of ApacheBench may be used in parallel to more fully saturate the target URL.